# How can I export a material as a single image

Tags: texturing

attached a pic of the material I want as a jpeg. it is a simple combination of a color and normal map, but I want both in one image, and this preview shows me exactly what I want. I would like to know if I can export this material as it looks in the preview [image: materialpreview]

Comment: Hi :). The preview shows you how it will look on a simple plane. So just add a plane, give it this material and render it or bake it.